# Let $A$ be a convex. Is it true that $\operatorname{aint} (A) \neq \emptyset \implies \operatorname{aint} (A) = \operatorname{int} (A)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces

I have recently come across this result.

> **Theorem:** Let $A$ be a convex subset of a t.v.s. $X$. If $\operatorname{int} (A) \neq \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{aint} (A) = \operatorname{int} (A)$.

Here $\operatorname{aint} (A)$ is the [algebraic interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466669/does-this-result-require-a-to-be-convex) of $A$.

**My attempt:** Clearly, $\operatorname{int} (A) \subset \operatorname{aint} (A)$. Let's prove the converse. Assume $a \in \operatorname{aint} (A)$. We want to show $a \in \operatorname{int} (A)$. Fix $b \in \operatorname{int} (A)$. There is $t>0$ such that $c := a+t(a-b) \in A$. It follows that $a = (1-\lambda)b+\lambda c$ with $\lambda := 1/ (1+t)$. Then $a \in U := (1-\lambda) \operatorname{int} (A) +\lambda c \subset A$. Notice that $(1-\lambda) \operatorname{int} (A)$ is open, so $U$ is open. This completes the proof.

1. Could you have a check on my attempt?
2. Is below related statement true? If not, please provide a counter-example.

> Let $A$ be a convex subset of a t.v.s. $X$. If $\operatorname{aint} (A) \neq \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{aint} (A) = \operatorname{int} (A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, this looks fine.
2. If this assertion would be true, you would (together with 1.) always have $\operatorname{aint}(A) = \operatorname{int}(A)$.

It is well known, that this equality holds if $A$ is a closed, convex subset of a Banach space.

Here are some counterexamples:

1. Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional normed space and $\ell \colon X \to \mathbb R$ be linear and unbounded. Then
   $$
   A = \{x \in X \mid |\ell(x)| < 1\}
   $$
   has empty interior, but non-empty algebraic interior.
2. Let $X = c_c$ be the space of finite sequences (equipped with the $\infty$-norm) and
   $$
   A = \{x \in X \mid |x_n| \le 1/n \forall n \in \mathbb N\}.
   $$
   Then, $A$ is convex and closed, has empty interior but non-empty algebraic interior.