# Does this theorem about algebraic/topological interiors hold in case $X$ is non-Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove the second statement of below result, taken from this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_interior#Properties_of_core) of Wikipedia.

[image]

In my below proof, I assume $X$ to be Hausdorff. The Hausdorff condition is to ensure that *every finite-dimensional Hausdorff t.v.s. [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465059/every-finite-dimensional-topological-separated-vector-space-is-isomorphic-and-ho/2465070#2465070) topologically isomorphic to some $\mathbb R^d$*. This result is then used in the proof of **Lemma 1**.

- Could you have a check on my attempt?
- Does the theorem hold in case $X$ is non-Hausdorff?

---

> **Theorem:** Let $A$ be a convex subset of a Hausdorff t.v.s. $X$. If $\dim A < +\infty$ then $\operatorname{aint} (A) = \operatorname{int} (A)$.

[Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470192/let-a-x-1-ldots-x-n1-be-an-affinely-independent-then-operatornam) Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional Hausdorff t.v.s. and $A:=\{x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}\} \subset V$ affinely independent. Then $\operatorname{int} (\operatorname{conv} A) \neq \emptyset$.

[Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468046/let-a-be-a-convex-is-it-true-that-operatornameaint-a-neq-emptyset-im) Let $A$ be a convex subset of a t.v.s. $X$. If $\operatorname{int} (A) \neq \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{aint} (A) = \operatorname{int} (A)$.

*Proof:* If $\operatorname{aint} (A) = \emptyset$, then we are done. Now consider the case $\operatorname{aint} (A) \neq \emptyset$. WLOG, we assume $0 \in \operatorname{aint} (A)$. For each $x \in X$, there is $t>0$ such that $tx \in A$. Then $A$ contains a basis of $X$, so $X = \operatorname{aff} (A)$. Hence $X$ is finite-dimensional. By **Lemma 1**, we get $\operatorname{int} (\operatorname{conv} A) \neq \emptyset$. Because $A$ is convex, $\operatorname{conv} A = A$ and thus $\operatorname{int} A \neq \emptyset$. The claim then follows from **Lemma 2**.

Comment: Consider tvs with anti discrete topology. Then the interior of a proper subset is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @freakish pointed in a comment, a counter-example is a t.v.s. $X$ with [anti-discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology). In this topology,  the only open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$.